# Windows 7 keep internet connection after IPSec established

Tags: ipsec, openswan, vpn

How I can keep internet connection after establishing IpSec connection to server?

I have followed to following link to establish IpSec server
http://rootmanager.com/ubuntu-ipsec-l2tp-windows-domain-auth/setting-up-openswan-xl2tpd-with-native-windows-clients.html

then following the below one to connect this server from Windows 7 machine.

http://confoundedtech.blogspot.com/2012/07/windows-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-connection-to.html

I am able to connect and properly sending data. But after establishing IPSec conenction, my internet connection is dropped. How I can keep both connection alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to have your system use the local gateway rather than the one on the remote system Right click on the connection icon and click Properties.   Click the Networking Tab and click on TCP/IP V4 to select and then click Properties.  Click Advanced and UNCHECK "Use default gateway on remote system"

You can also have issues if the network on the remote system and on the local system are the same. Very common when admins leave default network on devices like 192.168.0.X or 192.168.1.X

Comment: Thats is it. Thanks. It works. But I could not understand how it works.